# Is this sin for me too? PLEASE HELP!

Tags: salat, sin, alcohol

I was out with my friends and they were drinking alcohol. I did NOT drink alcohol.

I know for sure that anyone who drinks alcohol their prayers will not be accepted for 40 days.

Anyone who sits with someone drinking alcohol even if they don't drink, it is like they are sinning the same as the one who drinks alcohol. Is this true?

Does this mean my prayers are not accepted for 40 days? (even though I did not drink and was only with someone that drinks)

Answer (score 1):

You are sinful. Condoning a sin is a sin in itself. Both the person who commits the sin and the one who condones it are blameworthy. Imam Ahmad recorded that Umar Ibn al-Khattab said:

> “O people! I have heard the Messenger of God (peace
> and blessings be upon him) say, ‘Whoever believes in God and the Last
> Day **should not sit at a table where [alcoholic] drinks are served even
> if he does not drink with them** as this is tantamount to a tacit
> approval.’” 
>  **Narrated by Ahmad, 126; classed as Saheeh by al-Albaani in Irwa’ al-Ghaleel, 7/6.**

Comment: Does this mean my prayers for 40 days isn't accepted?

Comment: @Patience No, your prayers are still accepted because you didn't consume alcohol.